# Pagination Type for Healthcare Finder API

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

Does anyone know the type of pagination that should be used when making a getCountiesForZip request from the HealthCare finder API?

I'm trying to use it with Qlik Sense which offers the following types found at http://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/REST_connector_help/Content/1.0/Create-REST-connection/Pagination-scenarios.htm:

**Offset** uses a starting value from which to read additional records.

**Next token** uses a token that is passed to the URL call for the next set of records.

**Next URL** uses a value that contains the URL for the next set of records.

**Custom** is a special option that can be used when none of the other paging options are implemented.

Comment: Update: While testing this, changing it from None to Custom seems to accomplish what I'm looking for which is a unique key for each request but I don't know why this works. When it was set to none, the keys were all 1 but now they increment as desired.

Comment: go ahead and add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Changing it from **None** to **Custom** seems to accomplish what I'm looking for which is a unique key for each request. I'm not sure why this works but when it was set to **None**, the keys were all 1. When set to **Custom** they increment as desired.